# Google AppEngine: Is a default Client ID created when project is created?

Tags: google-app-engine

This [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/endpoints/annotations) states "a default client ID is automatically created and named for use by the project".
In my project under API Manager -> Credentials, I don't see any Client ID.
Is the documentation referred to older AppEngine's behavior?